A problem about Fubini's Theorem and norm
Let $f \in L_{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and for each $h > 0$, we defined: $$f_{h}(x) = \frac{1}{2h} \int_{(x-h,x+h)} f(t) \lambda(dt),$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
I want to prove that $\|f_h\|_{L_1} \le \|f\|_{L_1}$, but i didn't be able to aply the Fubini's theorem, because i can't wonder what integrable function over $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ defining for get the result.
I know that is need to estimate this: $$\|f_h\|_{L_1} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_{h}(t)|\lambda(dt) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\int_{(t-h,t+h)} f(s)\lambda(ds)|\lambda(dt),$$ But i don't know what $\lambda \times \lambda$-integrable function to take for aplying the Fubini's Theorem.
Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Consider the function $g(x,t)= \frac1{2h}\chi_{(x-h,x+h)}(t)f(t)$ where $\chi_{(x-h,x+h)}(t)$ is $1$ if $t\in(x-h,x+h)$ and $0$ otherwise

Use Tonelli to show that $|f_h|$ is $L^1$.

@BrunoAndrades Thank you very much!

Thank you very much! @copper.hat
